# Traversing an XML file with Jquery using multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, web

I am trying to get a specific child element from an XML doc based on multiple selectors. Below is what I was using to find all records with the matching room name. Note that I also need to filter by a specific date-time range based on the `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` fields. I am not a web guy so to help explain below is how I would do this in SQL:

```sql
SELECT EventName
FROM Events
WHERE RoomName = 'Ballroom A'
and StartDateTime > '2018-08-23T08:30:00' and EndDateTime < '2018-08-23T17:00:00'
```

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "data.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
    var nod = $(xml).find("Event RoomName:contains('Ballroom A')");
    var pNod = nod.parent();
    var name = $(pNod).find("EventName");
    alert(name.text());
  }
});
```

Below is a sample record in the exact format of the XML. I have tried chaining the finds and using .has, but nothing seems to produce anything.

```html
<GetEventsResponse>
  <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
  <StatusId>1000</StatusId>
  <StatusDescription>Success</StatusDescription>
  <StatusException/>
  <StatusCookie>Events came from cache</StatusCookie>
  <StatusTimeStamp>2018-08-23T09:20:09.0375049-06:00</StatusTimeStamp>
  <Events>
    <Event>
      <PropertyKey/>
      <PropertyName>HERE</PropertyName>
      <EventKey>...</EventKey>
      <EventName>EVENT 1002</EventName>
      <EventPostAs></EventPostAs>
      <GroupKey/>
      <GroupName/>
      <GroupLogoUrl/>
      <StartDateTime>2018-08-23T09:00:00</StartDateTime>
      <EndDateTime>2018-08-23T17:00:00</EndDateTime>
      <Building/>
      <RoomKey/>
      <RoomName>Ballroom A</RoomName>
      <MeetingKey/>
      <MeetingName/>
      <MeetingPostAs/>
      <MeetingType/>
      <AgreedAttendance>50</AgreedAttendance>
      <IsPostable>true</IsPostable>
      <IsExhibit>false</IsExhibit>
      <SecondaryEventPostAs/>
      <SecondaryGroupName/>
      <SecondaryRoomName/>
      <SecondaryMeetingName/>
      <SecondaryMeetingPostAs/>
      <VideoWallScreen>0</VideoWallScreen>
      <VideoWallPage>0</VideoWallPage>
      <VideoWallLine>0</VideoWallLine>
      <EventType/>
      <Status/>
      <StatusType/>
    </Event>
  </Events>
</GetEventsResponse>
```

Can anyone offer some assistance in what is the best method to get the data i need. Thanks.